# Connect points based on underlying road network in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, network, snapping

I have a road network layer. I also have the latitude and longitude of the bus stops in that road network. I want to connect a series of these stops but not using straight lines but via the underlying road network.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: As I do not have much information of your data based on your post I have the following questions: *Is your road network a road network or a network of buslines?* Do you use GTFS data for your bus stops and bus lines? Then it might be possible to select lines of your bus lines and bus stops based on the attributes tables and link them in such a way. *Is your dataset a large dataset?* Otherwise, a simple manual selection might do. Is it possible to provide more detailed information?

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. The road network I have does not contain the network of bus lines. It is just the layer of roads in a city. My data is not a large dataset and I am willing to draw manually. In case if I have to draw manually, how do I draw the lines exactly above the existing network?

Comment: Drawing lines in QGIS is possible and quite straightforward. See this short guide if you want to use your existing network as a guide: https://geo.nls.uk/urbhist/guides_vectorlayerqgis.html 

How are your roads given; lines, polygons? There might be other ways namely.